# Component renders and gives an error before the data is completely loaded from the API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am pulling data from a crypto coin API. It has 250 coins data in one request. But if I load all of them, the data is not loaded and component tries to render which gives an error. I am following the regular practice of await and useEffect but still the error is persistent.

```
const Home = () => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useContext(SearchContext);

  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const getCoinsData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await Axios.get(
        `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=true&price_change_percentage=1h%2C24h%2C7d`
      );
      setData(response.data);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getCoinsData();
  }, []);

  const negStyle = {
    color: "#D9534F",
  };
  const positiveStyle = {
    color: "#95CD41",
  };

  return (
    <div className="home">
      <div className="heading">
        <h1>Discover</h1>
        <hr className="line" />
      </div>
      {!loading || data ? (
        <div style={{ width: "100%", overflow: "auto" }}>
          <table *the entire table goes here* />
            
        </div>
      ) : (
        <img className="loading-gif" src={Loading} alt="Loading.." />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

This is the entire code. Still when I try to refresh, it gives errors based on how much data loads. Sometimes, .map function is not defined or toFixed is defined etc. It does not keep loading till the whole data is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show the errors and how did you initialize your state `loading` and `data` so we can debug better ?

Otherwise, what I usually do in this case is:

```
if (!loading && data) return <Table />;
return <img className="loading-gif" ... />;
```

Comment: Edited the question, please take a look

Comment: Well if the error come from the `Table`, we will need to take a look of `<Table />` code.

I have no idea what is `toFixed` error base on your code, if you can have a screenshort of the code to see where the error came from ?

Anyway, what I can suggest is initilialize `data` by empty array instead of null:

`const [data, setData] = useState([]);`

And checking condition should be:

`!loading && data && data.length > 0`

At least you can avoid errors from `null` value.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider, useQuery } from "react-query";
import axios from "axios";
import React from "react";
import { Image } from "@chakra-ui/image";

const Crypto = () => {
  const { data, isLoading } = useQuery("crypto", () => {
    const endpoint =
      "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&per_page=80&page=1&sparkline=true&price_change_percentage=1h%2C24h%2C7d";
    return axios.get(endpoint).then(({ data }) => data);
  });

  return (
    <>
      {!isLoading && data ? (
        data?.map((e, id) => <Image key={id} src={e.image} />)
      ) : (
        <p>Loading</p>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient();

  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <Crypto />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandBox Link, Preview](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-cori-mxub0?file=/src/App.js:23-858)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jyn9k.png)